# Sharing such as web layer from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online and the layer have less features, why?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I have shared a multi polygon layer with 729 rows and 27 features. After opening in map viewer in ArcGIS Online is displayed only 3 rows and 2 features.

The data is time enabled.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What were the precise and detailed steps that you performed when sharing the layer?  Did you have any selections on it or a geoprocessing extent set when you shared it?

Comment: What is in the 702 rows without features?

Comment: In 729 rows are time series daily data for every country (27 features) about Covid-19 with geometry column. I don't had any selection or geoprocessing extent.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own query, if the data is enabled with a time slider, it will only show the features in that time duration, reflecting the same in the attributes table. This is as per design.

Navigate to the Data tab in the Item details page of the feature layer(hosted) and check how many features are there, IF you still see only 2 features there, it's something else triggering this.

[image]